# Как создать пустое окно c OpenGL?

Tags: c#, .net, opengl

Начал изучать OpenGL по [этому](http://pmg.org.ru/nehe/nehe01.htm) туториалу.

Все в точности переписал, убрал **_T**, т.к. не поддерживается новыми компиляторами, а туториал довольно старый. По этой же причине добавил кое-где явное приведение типов.

И вот при компиляции получаю окно с сообщением об ошибке:

> Unable to start program
> 'C:\Users\Дима\Documents\Visual
> Studio2013\Projects\OpenGL_PMG\Debug\OpenGL_PMG.exe'.
> Не удается найти указанный файл.

Не пойму, что не так.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы используете старый туториал, используйте старые версии библиотеке OpenGL - например в DevC++ 4 и Visual Studio C++ 6.0 разные версии, и код соответственно будет разный. если Вы хотите изучать OpenGL, загуглите TaoFramework. Более того, скажу - http://esate.ru/uroki/OpenGL/uroki-OpenGL-c-sharp/ - вот вам ссылка на первоклассный (я считаю) и адекватный учебник по этому делу, сам по ним занимался, все примеры рабочие, и что я считаю важно - с автором статей можно связаться, он мне когда-то лично на мои вопросы отвечал =)

Удачи!

Comment: старый библиотеки openGL - window.Open() // old opengl32.dll;
в новых версиях используется (как вариант) glut.dll : glutCreateWindow();
Надеюсь, я помог. А вообще, я посоветовал бы использовать DevC++, он отлично для этих целей подходит.

Answer (score 0):

1. При чем здесь отметка "C#"?
2. Ошибка более чем общего характера. Скорее всего, при компоновке ошибка.

Лично мое мнение: сам недавно начал изучать ogl, и уроки по вышеуказанной ссылке я бы не советовал.   
Лучше http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/ru/
http://ogltutor.netau.net
http://tempload.com/category/opengl/

Comment: Спасибо, тоже почитаю. Просто я этот код полдня набирал, хочется посмотреть результат.